# Apache/Drupal: Drupal website with links wrongly pointing to another Drupal site

Tags: php, apache, drupal, hyperlink

At my job we have Apache installed in an Ubuntu 16.04 lts server, the folder where the websites are is /var/www/html

We have a Drupal website in /var/www/html/version1 . The problem is that after copying the folder of the site and naming it /var/www/html/version2 to do some testing, we deleted /var/www/html/version2 and when going to localhost:8080/version1/  the links in that site inexplicably pointed to version2 ie localhost:8080/version2/news

That was yesterday, today the links are pointing correctly to localhost:8080/version1/news but If I access from a public ip that is opened, ie [public_ip]:8080/version1/ and click the links of the news it redirects to [public_ip]:8080/version2/news and obviously it gives page not found.
If I go to [public_ip]:8080/version1/news directly it access it without any problem.

Where is the problem? I can provide the configuration files from apache or the sites. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Could this be a browser HTTP header caching problem?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, we tested it after erasing the browser cache

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was on Drupal, According to what they say here https://www.drupal.org/node/845026 Drupal does not save html files, it generates them 'on the fly' by consulting a database.

So to update the links you have to clean the cache of Drupal

Htt ps://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/clearing-or-rebuilding-drupals-cache

Htt ps://www.drupal.org/node/1507640

Htt p://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21434/how-do-i-clear-cache-using-an-sql-query

The problem was solved by the Drupal administrator simply by login in the admin panel.